# Make title attribute appear instantly on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

is there a possibility to make a title attribute of an anchor tag appear instantly on mouseover   not just after seconds.
Any solution in JavaScript/jQuery and CSS is good.

Comment: Not with the native `title` attribute, no; with CSS you can emulate it (for most, non-void, elements) though.

Comment: The delay is controlled by the browser, and not something you can alter programmatically.

Comment: This comes close http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

Comment: @DavidThomas you could use javascript to get the title attribute's contents then put that into some tool-tip like element, no?

Comment: @Woodrow: of course.

Answer (score 11):

The handling of the `title` attribute is browser-dependent, and no APIs have been defined to control it, still less specified in specs. This includes the delay, the duration of the display, the font used, font size, etc.

There are other techniques that can be used *instead of* the `title` attribute. Some of them have been mentioned in other answers. Note that simple “CSS tooltips” can be implemented in pure CSS rather simply and flexibly. When using these techniques, the data to be shown is usually *not* in a `title` attribute, since its handling is browser-dependent, so there would be a risk of having your special tooltip display *and* a browser’s implementation of `title`. Though it is possible to prevent the latter, when scripting is enabled, it is simpler to use an attribute that has no default effect on anything, such as `data-title=...` or `data-tooltip=...`.

Answer (score 9):

One approach:

```js
// textFrom : String, the attribute from which the text
//            should come,
// delta :    String or Number, the distance from the cursor at
//            which the tooltip should appear
function instantTooltips(textFrom, delta) {
  // if delta exists, and can be parsed to a number, we use it,
  // otherwise we use the default of 5:
  delta = parseFloat(delta) ? parseFloat(delta) : 5;

  // function to handle repositioning of the created tooltip:
  function reposition(e) {
    // get the tooltip element:
    var tooltip = this.nextSibling;
    // setting the position according to the position of the
    // pointer:
    tooltip.style.top = (e.pageY + delta) + 'px';
    tooltip.style.left = (e.pageX + delta) + 'px';
  }

  // get all elements that have an attribute from which we
  // want to get the tooltip text from:
  var toTitle = document.querySelectorAll('[' + textFrom + ']'),
    //create a span element:
    span = document.createElement('span'),
    // find if we should use textContent or innerText (IE):
    textProp = 'textContent' in document ? 'textContent' : 'innerText',
    // caching variables for use in the upcoming forEach:
    parent, spanClone;
  // adding a class-name (for CSS styling):
  span.classList.add('createdTooltip');
  // iterating over each of the elements with a title attribute:
  [].forEach.call(toTitle, function(elem) {
    // reference to the element's parentNode:
    parent = elem.parentNode;
    // cloning the span, to avoid creating multiple elements:
    spanClone = span.cloneNode();
    // setting the text of the cloned span to the text
    // of the attribute from which the text should be taken:
    spanClone[textProp] = elem.getAttribute(textFrom);

    // inserting the created/cloned span into the
    // document, after the element:
    parent.insertBefore(spanClone, elem.nextSibling);

    // binding the reposition function to the mousemove
    // event:
    elem.addEventListener('mousemove', reposition);

    // we're setting textFrom attribute to an empty string
    // so that the CSS will still apply, but which
    // shouldl still not be shown by the browser:
    elem.setAttribute(textFrom, '');
  });
}

// calling the function:
instantTooltips('title', 15);
```

```css
[title] {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 1em 0;
}

/*
  hiding, and styling, the elements we'll be creating
*/
[title] + span.createdTooltip {
  display: none;
  border: 2px solid #f90;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  padding: 0.2em 0.5em;
  border-radius: 0.75em;
}

/*
  showing the created elements on hovering the element we want to
  show tooltips for
*/
[title]:hover + span.createdTooltip {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<span title="This is the span's title">A span element</span>
<img src="http://placekitten.com/g/250/250" title="A kitten." />
<input title="This is an input element's title." value="This input has a title" />
```

References:

- [Conditional ('ternary') operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).
- [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.createElement).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll).
- [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList).
- [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in).
- [`Node.cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.cloneNode).
- [`Node.nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nextSibling).
- [`Node.parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.parentNode).
- [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat).
- [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof).

Comment: I used this in my react app and it works like a charm. Brilliant piece of code David. 

Answer (score 3):

You can not do it with default tooltips but you can use jQuery plugins for tooltip or bootstrap. and the best way to create this is create custom tooltip.

http://tech.pro/tutorial/930/jquery-custom-tooltips

Here are some references which you can use

Simpletip:  http://craigsworks.com/projects/simpletip/

Bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips

Answer (score 2):

Bootstraps ToolTip plugin does a pretty good job of this and is a lot more responsive / quicker.

Just requires the default Bootstrap files to run.

CSS can be changed to suit your requirements.

More information and examples can be shown here:

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips

Answer (score 2):

You could hide the tite on `mouseover` and append a span. then remove the span and reinstate the title on `mouseout`

```
$('a').hover(function(e){
    title = $(this).attr('title');
    $(this).append('<span>Im Super Fast!!!</span>')
    $(this).removeAttr('title');
},
function(e){
    $('span', this).remove();
    $(this).attr('title',title);
});
```

Check the example - http://jsfiddle.net/1z3catx3/1/

note: You would of course need to style the `span`

Answer (score 2):

tray this with box-shadow and border array:

```
$('a').hover(function(e){

    title = $(this).attr('alt');
    $(this).append('<span>'+title+'</span>')


},
function(e){
    $('span', this).remove();


});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1z3catx3/112/

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    
    [data-title]:hover:after {
      opacity: 1;
      transition: all 0.1s ease 0.5s;
      visibility: visible;
    }
    
    [data-title]:after {
      content: attr(data-title);
      position: absolute;
      bottom: -1.6em;
      z-index: 99999;
      visibility: hidden;
      white-space: nowrap;
      background-color: lightgray;
      color: #111;
      font-size: 90%;
      font-weight: lighter;
      padding: 1px 5px 2px 5px;
      box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #222222;
      opacity: 0;
      border: 1px solid #111111;
      border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    }
    
    [data-title] {
      position: relative;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<p data-title="also you can put it here for toltip other element ">my element </p>

</body>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).