# Display text instead of cursor on image hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cursor

Does anybody know a way to display custom text instead of cursor on image hover? ideally this would be a title or alt attribute form image.

If not is there any way to display the text under the cursor?

I simply need a thing close to normal title attribute behavior, I just need it to display instantly and with my styliong.

note: I know about this way:

```
 a[title]:hover:after {
  content: attr(title);
  padding: 4px 8px;
  color: #333;
  position: absolute;...
```

unfortunately it displays title after the image, and i need it over the image, as the cursor moves :)

any help would be appreciated

thanx!!

Comment: Have you looked at this question: "[Make title attribute appear instantly on hover](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26259665/make-title-attribute-appear-instantly-on-hover)"? I think [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26261233/82548), there, should be applicable to your problem.

Comment: Hello, I don't think Your answer is correct for my question. I need a text on image instead of cursor (but moving like cursor). But your answers got me on track and i Think http://stevenbenner.github.io/jquery-powertip/ is for me.

Comment: Fair enough; reopened. But please clarify exactly, and explicitly, what you want. Because while I think I understand what you *mean*, I'm not sure that's quite what you're saying.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear.  I will test the http://stevenbenner.github.io/jquery-powertip/ tomorrow and close the topic if it meets my needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in jQuery like this:

```
var title = "";
$(document).mousemove(function (e) {    

    $(".image_container").each(function(i, v){

        var container = v;
        var img = $(this).children()[0];

        if((e.pageY < $(img).offset().top || 
           e.pageY > $(img).offset().top + $(img).height() ||
           e.pageX < $(img).offset().left ||
           e.pageX > $(img).offset().left + $(img).width()) ){

            if( $(container).children().length == 2){
               $(container).children()[0].title = $($(container).children()[1]).html();
               container.removeChild($(container).children()[1]);
            }

        }
        else{  
            if($(container).children().length == 1){
                console.log("printing title");
                title = $("<div class='img_title'>" + $(container).children()[0].title + "</div>");
                $(container).children()[0].title = "";
                $(container).append(title);
            }
            title.offset({
                top: (e.pageY ? e.pageY : e.clientX),
                left: (e.pageX ? e.pageX : e.clientY)
            });
        }
    });

});
```

and with css

```
.img_title {
    display: table;
    background: #888888;
    position: absolute;
}
.image_container {
    cursor: none;
    display: table;    
}
```

and put images like this:

```
<div class="image_container">
    <img src="url" title="Text to follow mouse on hover" />
</div>
```

Check it out here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pcgksokt/4/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for Your answer  Caeth, This is almost what I need. I just need it to "follow the cursor". so text instead of cursor moving :) any idea for that?? thanx a lot?

Comment: @Piotr I've changed it so it follows the mouse, check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/pcgksokt/1/

Comment: Unfortunately, there is e big lag when moving Out from image. the "title stays" text instead of cursor sometimes for more than 5 sec.  (but not always)

There is also major problem with IE 9 (and maybe others)

Comment: @Piotr I've updated the fiddle again, check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/pcgksokt/4/

It should work in IE9  now, and I think the lag is gone.

Comment: Ehh, on Mac works great (safari, chrome,FF) on Windows 7 and ie9 (only ie I have in virtual machine) it fails. the cursor hides (thanks of css) but nothink else shows :/

Comment: @Piotr Hmm that's weird, it works for me Win7 IE9 (the real deal :))